Assign a SV port
I am wondering if this systemVerilog syntax is behaviorally correct :
module m (input [3:0] in1);
endmodule

module top();
  assign inst.in1 = 4'b1010;
 
  m inst (.in1());
  
endmodule


I am asking because I noticed some strange result when running formal logic equivalence checking.
Is there another better way to drive the instance port in1 ?

I edited the title !
The question is just if this syntax is correct from a behavioral point of view? i.e if the synthesis will be correct? ...

Hierarchical references are generally not considered synthesizable.
If you want to drive a constant into an input, you can write
module top();
  m inst (.in1(4'b1010)); 
endmodule

or
module top();
  wire [3:0]  in = 4'b1010;
 
  m inst (.in1(in));
  
endmodule

